# Probability problem (probability axioms problem)

Tags: probability

I want to see if  I can show this assertion: if $\mathbb{P}(A) = 0$, then $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = 0$ where $B$ is any event. Do I need more information to show this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $P(AB)$. Is it $P(A\cup B)$ (The probability that either $A$ or $B$ occurs), or $P(A\cap B)$ (The probability that both $A$ and $B$ occur)?

Comment: sorry! It is the probability of the intersection of the event A and B

Comment: $P(A\cap B)≤P(A)$ no matter what $A,B$ are (well, so long as their probabilities are defined).

Comment: Then we have $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. Now as $P(A)=0$, we can say that $P(B)=P(A\cup B)$.

$\therefore P(A\cap B)=0+P(B)-P(B)=0$

Comment: I don´t  understand why this happend: as P(A)=0, we can say that P(B)=P(A∪B), I agree that if it is true, we are done, but can you explain me how can we ensure that? Thank you!

Comment: @RebecaAngulo  If $C \subseteq D$, then $\Pr(C) \leq \Pr(D)$. Since $A \cap B \subseteq A$, $\Pr(A \cap B) \leq \Pr(A) = 0$.  Since a probability must be nonnegative, $\Pr(A \cap B) \geq 0$.  Since $\Pr(A \cap B) \geq 0$ and $\Pr(A \cap B) \leq 0$, it follows that $\Pr(A \cap B) = 0$.  This argument hinges on whether you have proved the first statement.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Thanks!

Comment: @lulu Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I leave the technicalities aside for the shake of simplicity.

You have that $P(A)=0$. In any case for any events $A$ and $B$ obviously $(A\cap B)\subseteq A$. Now for any probability measure $P$ if $X\subseteq Y$ then $P(X)\leq P(Y)$. So in our case $P(A\cap B) \leq P(A)$ and $P(A)=0$ therefore we have $P(A\cap B)\leq 0$. Finally, for any probability measure $P$ it holds that $P(X)\geq 0$ for any set $X$.

Therefore one can easily conclude that this probability must be exactly $0$ since that is the only value that satisfies both inequalities.